# Rails nested_forms not displaying fields when dynamically adding extra objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm currently using the nested_forms gem and  I'm trying to be able to add multiple landlords to a property.

At the moment the associations are quite deep:
Property -> Landlord -> Contact_Detail -> Address

In my Property controller I'm building the associations and the initial form is displayed correctly. However, after using the add fields button, there are no fields. I know it is something to do with the object not getting built, but I can't understand why.

Here's my Property model:

```
belongs_to :address
belongs_to :estate_agent
belongs_to :property_style

has_and_belongs_to_many :landlord
has_and_belongs_to_many :tenancy_agreement

attr_accessible :landlord_attributes, :address_attributes, :estate_agent_attributes, 
:property_style_attributes, :sector, :reference , :occupied, :available_date, :property_style_attributes,...

accepts_nested_attributes_for :landlord, :address, :estate_agent, :property_style, :tenancy_agreement
```

And here's the new function in the Property controller:

```
  def new
    @property = Property.new
    @property.build_address
    @property.landlord.build.build_contact_detail.build_address

    @property.estate_agent_id = current_user.estate_agent_id

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @property }
    end
end
```

I've had quite a few attempts at this, but can't see where I'm going wrong, is it a problem with the nested_form gem not supporting this many levels of association or the type of association?

Thanks!

*EDIT*
Changes made:

```
belongs_to :address
belongs_to :estate_agent
belongs_to :property_style

has_and_belongs_to_many :landlords
has_and_belongs_to_many :tenancy_agreements

attr_accessible :landlords_attributes, :address_attributes, :estate_agent_attributes, 
:property_style_attributes, :sector, :reference , :occupied, :available_date,  :property_style_attributes,...

accepts_nested_attributes_for :landlords, :address, :estate_agent, :property_style, :tenancy_agreements
```

Properties controller:

```
@property.landlords.build.build_contact_detail.build_address
```

Landlords model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
```

Here is my view:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@property) do |f| %>
<% if @property.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@property.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this property from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @property.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<h2>Landlords</h2>

<%= f.fields_for :landlords %>

<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Landlord", :landlords %></p>

 <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've specified "landlord" as an [irregular inflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html), Rails will assume that it is singular. Many-to-many associations should be declared in the plural.

Try changing the many-to-many associations to:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :landlords
has_and_belongs_to_many :tenancy_agreements
```

You'll also need to change all calls to these to be plural as well. In addition, you must change the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to `landlords`, and the `attr_accessible` from `landlord_attributes` to `landlords_attributes`.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that was the standard naming convention which had to used. I've changed it to plural everywhere, even in view and controller (was causing errors) but it still works as previously. I've noticed in my landlord model it has `has_and_belongs_to_many :property` will I need to change these to plural too? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried updating the landlord model to :properties, but still the same issue. Is it a problem with using the habtm association?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use both awesome-nested-forms and cocoon and it still wouldn't work.

In the end, I found a workaround by building the object in the partial and not in the controller. Like this:

```
<% f.object.build_contact_detail.build_address %>
```

I hope this helps someone else!